# python.exe the fastcgi process exited unexpectedly

Tags: python, django, fastcgi, iis-8

i have some reasons witch i am stuck to use `django` on windows machine. i was wondering how to configure `django` on a `windows sesrver 2012 r2 with iis 8.5`. so i followed the tutorial [here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html). 
i did what the tutorial says and it is pretty much straight forward what i am gonna do for any kind of application i want to run with `iis`. 
but i get the following error `the fastcgi process exited unexpectedly`.
here is what i have provided as executable for `wfastcgi` module:

```
E:\venvs\...\Scripts\python.exe|E:\venvs\...\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py
```

i removed the `wfastcgi.py` part after | from handler mapping and error changed to script processor could not find the config for fastcgi configuration and i figured out the error must be related to the `wfastcgi.py` file. but i could not find the issue here. so i was wondering what can be the issue? and what are my options are here. 
 has any one been able to use django on a windows machine?? jsut in case my python version is python 3.6

Comment: turns out the wfastcgi is not compatible with python3.5 and python3.6. just install python 3.4.2 and you are as good as a go person ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem as you but managed to solve this by using Python 3.4.2 version. Follow the exact steps as described in this tutorial [Django with IIS](https://www.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/23/running-a-django-application-on-windows-server-2012-with-iis/) and avoid using Python 3.5 or above because it seems that there are compatibility issues. The stack I used was IIS version 10, Windows 10, Python 3.4.2 and Django 1.11.2.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading `wfastcgi` to the latest version

```
pip install wfastcgi --upgrade
```

solved it for me: `Python 3.6.6`, [`wfastcgi 3.0.0`](https://pypi.org/project/wfastcgi/3.0.0/)

Answer (score -1):

In my Case I was facing the same issue i.e. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jfZa.png)

Mine is a Django App used for APIs that queries data from back-end platforms. This issue was only for specific filters that the API was using in queries while for other values in filters it worked great.

My Config file did not have a fastCgi tag and I added below mentioned part to top of system.webServer in config file. Yes off course it gave few errors here and there corresponding to activityTimeout and requestTimeout. Tried increasing up-to 900 and 601 respectively and then it worked for me. But could not understand cause of the issue as query that API was running for which i was facing this issue was not taking that long at all. I would like to understand that.

```
<fastCgi>
   <application fullPath="D:\Python34\python.exe|D:\Python34\Scripts\wfastcgi.py" 
        arguments=""
        maxInstances="4"
        idleTimeout="300"
        activityTimeout="900"
        requestTimeout="601"
        instanceMaxRequests="10000"
        protocol="NamedPipe"
        flushNamedPipe="false">
   </application>
</fastCgi>
```